# More efficient double coalesce join alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, coalesce

I have a procedure with a (slightly more complex) version of the below:

```
CREATE PROC sp_Find_ID (
    @Match1 varchar(10),
    @Match2 varchar(10)
) AS

DECLARE @ID int

SELECT @ID = ID
FROM Table1
WHERE Match1 = @Match1
    AND Coalesce(Match2,@Match2,'') = Coalesce(@Match2,Match2,'')

SELECT @ID ID
```

Essentially Match1 is a mandatory match, but Match2 is both optional on the input to the procedure, and on the table being searched. The 2nd match succeeds where the input and/or the table Match2 values are null, or where they're both the same (not null) value.

My question is: Is there a more efficient (or even more readable) way of doing this?

I've used this method a few times, and I feel slightly sullied each time (subjective dirtiness admittedly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a more efficient (or even more readable) way of doing this?

The example you provided, using COALESCE/etc is [non-sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable).  You need to separate things so only what *needs to be present* in the query is run:

```
DECLARE @ID int

IF @Match2 IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

  SELECT @ID = t.id
    FROM TABLE1 t
   WHERE t.match1 = @Match1
     AND (t.match2 = @Match2 OR t.match2 IS NULL)

END
ELSE
BEGIN

  SELECT @ID = t.id
    FROM TABLE1 t
   WHERE t.match1 = @Match1

END

SELECT @ID ID
```

If you want this to occur in a single SQL statement, dynamic SQL is the only real alternative.  I highly recommend reading [The curse and blessing of dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) before reading further:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = N' SELECT @ID = t.id
                    FROM TABLE1 t
                   WHERE t.match1 = @Match1 '

    SET @SQL = @SQL + CASE 
                        WHEN @Match2 IS NOT NULL THEN
                          ' AND (t.match2 = @Match2 OR t.match2 IS NULL) ' 
                        ELSE 
                          ' '
                      END

BEGIN

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                     N'@ID INT OUTPUT, @Match1 VARCHAR(10), @Match2 VARCHAR(10)',
                     @ID, @Match1, @Match2

END
```

Comment: The `Match1 = @Match1` bit is sargable though so dependant on how selective that is that could mitigate this.

Comment: Very interesting, I may have to revise some of my previous query design.

Comment: The Match2 part is likely to be on less than 30 rows, whereas Match1 is ~ 50000.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Yeah, the match1 stuff is sargable, it's when using an IS NULL/COALESCE/ISNULL in brackets that things get non-sargable.

Comment: @OMG Assuming a composite index on `match1, match2` SQL Server would do a seek in on `match1` but then have to scan the 30 matching rows to evaluate the second part. Over time could add up (+1)

Answer (score 4):

Avoiding OR and ISNULL etc

- The EXCEPT bit returns no rows if either side IS NULL
- Match2 <> @Match2 means exclude non-NULL non-matching

Something like this

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Table1

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (ID int NOT NULL, Match1 int NOT NULL, Match2 int NULL)
INSERT dbo.Table1 VALUES (1, 55, 99), (2, 55, NULL)

DECLARE @Match1 int = 55, @Match2 int

SELECT ID
FROM
    (
    SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Match1 = @Match1
    EXCEPT -- @Match2 = NULL, match both rows (99, NULL)
    SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Match2 <> @Match2
    ) foo

SET @Match2 = -1
SELECT ID
FROM
    (
    SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Match1 = @Match1
    EXCEPT -- @Match2 = -1, match ID = 2 only where Match2 IS NULL
    SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Match2 <> @Match2
    ) foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is any more preferable.

```
SELECT @ID = ID
FROM Table1
WHERE Match1 = @Match1
    AND ((Match2 = @Match2) OR Coalesce(Match2,@Match2) IS NULL)
```

Comment: Won't "Match2 = @Match2" null the whole clause if either are null?

Comment: No. `unknown or true` = `true` and `unknown or false` = `unknown`. [3 valued logic truth table](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/)

Comment: Null logic is even more mind boggling than I at first feared.

Comment: It makes sense though. If part of an `or` is true then it doesn't matter if the rest is true or false we know the statement as a whole is true.

Comment: Presumably there's a minor speed improvement in using IsNull instead of a two-value Coalesce?

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple to me?  I must be missing something.. you dont need the  Coalesce

```
SELECT @ID = ID
 FROM Table1
 WHERE Match1 = @Match1
    AND (
          (Match2 is null and  @Match2 is null)
           or
           @Match2=Match2
    )

SELECT @ID ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought this should do it - providing that the `@Match2` value will be `NULL` if it is optional.

```
CREATE PROC sp_Find_ID (
    @Match1 varchar(10),
    @Match2 varchar(10)
) AS

DECLARE @ID int

SELECT @ID = ID
FROM Table1
WHERE Match1 = @Match1
    AND Match2 = IsNull(@Match2, Match2)

SELECT @ID ID
```

Comment: If `Match2` is null then `NULL = NULL` is unknown not true.

Comment: @Martin - ah yes good point.  This solution requires Match2 to not be Null